# Is there a way I can check a function parameter has an allowed value before runtime with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an AngularJS service coded in Typescript. I call the functions of the service with a parameter like this setFalse('retrieve'):

```
class StateService implements IStateService {

    state = [];

    get = (property: string) => {
        return this.state[property];
    }
    setFalse = (property: string) => {
        this.state[property] = false;
    }  
    setNull = (property: string) => {
        this.state[property] = null;
    }
    setTrue = (property: string) => {
        this.state[property] = true;
    }

    // more code here

}
```

Is there some way that I could remove the need for the quoted string 'retrieve', use a constant or check the values being used before run time?

Comment: Would an [`enum`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-enum) give you what you want?  The values are numeric, but you can get the name if that's what you need.

Comment: Yeah that might be good. How could I implement an Enum here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Is there some way that I could remove the need for the quoted string 'retrieve'?

You could desugar the overload, and provide lots of different versions of the function.

```
//just to give the idea
function setFalse_retrieve(){ return setFalse('retrieve') }
```

The upside of doing this is that its really typesafe and there is no way to ever call setFalse with a bad parameter. The downside is that there is lots of boilerplate and you can't pass around a `property` value if you want to.

### 2. Use a constant?

Typescript has an enum feature for this:

```
enum Properties { retrieve, frobnicate };
```

You can now use `Properties.retrieve` instead of "retrieve" in your code and it will catch any typos in the enum name.

```
Properties.retriev; // Error: The property 'retriev' does not exist on value of type 'typeof Properties'.
```

Just be aware that Typescript makes the enum values be integers so you will need to convert them to strings when calling the Angular functions:

```
var enumProperty = Properties.retrieve;     // 0
var strProperty = Properties[enumProperty]; // "retrieve"
```

The downside of the enum approach is that you can pass any number where an enum value is expected and the error will not be detected at runtime (do don't do that):

```
var x:Property = 10; // :(
```

### 3. Use a constant or check the values being used before run time

Typescript has function overloading on function constants but AFAIK, you can only use it to specialize return types depending on inputs, not to restrict your valid inputs to a set of constants. That is, you would still need to have a generic case that accepts any string, which is not what you want.